proof that for linear map $A$ $m(A(E))=|\operatorname{det} A| m(E) \quad \forall E \in \mathcal{M}$
I have to prove this theorem
$\begin{aligned}
&\text { let } A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \text { a linear map ,then  }\\
&m(A(E))=|\operatorname{det} A| m(E) \quad \forall E \in \mathcal{M}
\end{aligned}$
where $\mathcal{M}$ are lebesgue measurable set
this is ,skipping some details; the proof my professor wrote
(suppose we have already proved that $m(A(E))=cm(E)$)
now we only have to prove that $c=|det A|$
if $A=R \in O(n)$, then
part  $1$
$$
m\left(R\left(B_1\right)\right)=m\left(B_1\right)
$$
where $B_1$ is the unitary ball
so the formula is valid with $1=|\operatorname{det} R|$;
now part $2$

if $A=\operatorname{diag}\left(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\right)$ con $\lambda_i>0$, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
m\left(A\left([0,1]^n\right)\right)=m\left(\left[0, \lambda_1\right] \times \cdots \times\left[0, \lambda_n\right]\right) \\
& =\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n=\operatorname{det} A
\end{aligned}
$$
and again the formula is true
now part $3$
using a linear algebra lemma we know that if we call $D$ diagonal matrix and  $R, R' \in O(n)$ we have
\begin{aligned}
m(A(E))=m\left(R^{\prime} D R(E)\right) \\
& =\left|\operatorname{det} R^{\prime}\right| m(D R(E)) \\
& =\left|\operatorname{det} R^{\prime}\right||\operatorname{det} D| m(R(E)) \\
& =\left|\operatorname{det} R^{\prime}\right||\operatorname{det} D \| \operatorname{det} R| m(E) \\
& =|\operatorname{det} A| m(E)
\end{aligned}
and my question is we have proved only in particular cases  part  1 and 2 , respectively for a ball and for a cube , and in the part 3 he uses the same formulas prived in part 1 and 2  like they are true for all subset $E$ and this is what I don't understand .
my solution  I have tried to generalize part 2 in this way
$\forall E \exists Q_i :E=\cup Q_i$ disjoint so $f(E)=\cup f(Q_i)$ and $f(Q_i)$ are disjoint because $f$ is injective   so $m(f(E))=\sum m(f(Q_i))=|det A| \sum m(Q_i)=|det A| m(E)$
but still I don't know how to generalize part 1...
